# JSON property returning undefined

Tags: javascript, php, json, stringify

So I am creating a store catalog as a personal project.  I have two basic filters (category and subcategory).  I was just returning all the content server side when I decided I wanted to work with some JSON.  So I used json_encode(array()); to send the json data back.

When I console log, everything looks fine.  Snippet:

```
{
    "product": [
        {
            "productID": "1",
            "name": "Black Socks",
            "description": "Lorem ipsum no facer prompta vim, movet ubique qui ei. Per no regione aliquid, ea mei nulla scribentur liberavisse.",
            "price": "6.99",
            "stock": "25",
            "image": "placeholder.png",
            "category_id": "1",
            "subcategory_id": "1"
        }
}
```

But when I try to access a property, say *name*, it returns undefined.

```
 function displayAll() {
  var category = document.getElementById('category');
  var option = category.options[category.selectedIndex].value;
  var catalogDiv = document.getElementById('catalog');
  var allItems;

  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function (category) {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      catalog = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
      catalog = JSON.stringify(catalog, null, 4);

      console.log(catalog.name);  //<- Returns undefined

      catalogDiv.innerHTML = 'Success';
    }
  }; //End anon function

  //request_type, URL, boolean (is asynchronous)
  xhttp.open('POST', '../content/no_filter.php', true);

  //Correct header content
  xhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

  //Sends post data
  xhttp.send('option=' + option);

} //End display all
```

Here is a link to my source code: https://github.com/WordWizard/store-catalog

Comment: What is the purpose of `JSON.stringify`?

Comment: I think you're missing the closing `]` (or it's defined later in your code and is just omitted), also wouldn't it be `catalog[0].name` if your `product` contains an array of objects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never used stringify() function but I've read the docs and it says it converts a JSON object into a String. You are trying to access a String property so it returns undefined.

Try to comment or delete the following line:

```
catalog = JSON.stringify(catalog, null, 4);
```

What you want is a JSON object, not a string ;)

Comment: That returns `{Object { product: Array[10] } }`.  When I try to access a property of catalog: `console.log(catalog.name);` or `console.log(catalog[0].name);`, they return undefined.

Comment: Okay, I found I need to reference the product object inside the the catalog.  `console.log(catalog.product[0]);` works :)

Answer (score 1):

```
if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
  catalog = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
  // catalog = JSON.stringify(catalog, null, 4); // remove these line

  console.log(catalog.name);  //<- Returns undefined

  catalogDiv.innerHTML = 'Success';
}
```

At the line you have convert your JSON object to string. So you can't get name from this string.

If remove this line, will work fine.

```
{
   "product": [
        {
           "productID": "1",
           "name": "Black Socks",
           "description": "Lorem ipsum no facer prompta vim, movet ubique qui ei. Per no regione aliquid, ea mei nulla scribentur liberavisse.",
           "price": "6.99",
           "stock": "25",
           "image": "placeholder.png",
           "category_id": "1",
           "subcategory_id": "1"
        }
    ] // close your array properly.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change your code like this:

```
function displayAll() {
  var category = document.getElementById('category');
  var option = category.options[category.selectedIndex].value;
  var catalogDiv = document.getElementById('catalog');
  var allItems;

  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function (category) {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      catalog = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(catalog,null,4));
      console.log(catalog)
      console.log(catalog.paroduct[0].name);  

      catalogDiv.innerHTML = 'Success';
    }
  }; //End anon function

  //request_type, URL, boolean (is asynchronous)
  xhttp.open('POST', '../content/no_filter.php', true);

  //Correct header content
  xhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

  //Sends post data
  xhttp.send('option=' + option);

} //End display all
```